# Display full FROM email address in Outlook

Tags: security, outlook, phishing

I'm trying to do phishing mitigation in the Outlook desktop app, and I've seen a number of cases where the display name is so long that the email address gets truncated, e.g.

> From: Microsoft email account activity notifications admin@microsoft.completely.bogus.example.com

might get truncated in the view pane to

> From: Microsoft email account activity notifications <admin@microsoft.com

which looks at least superficially legit.

Is there a way to ensure that the full email address is displayed? Yes, I know that users *can* mouse over the email address to see who the email is from, but I want to eliminate barriers to good email security.

Ideally, I would like to set this in a GPO.

Comment: How are the mails displayed by your outlook client received? You probably have the option to simply reject (start with audit-only!) mail that Outlook cannot properly render. Anecdotal evidence: This has similar benefit/collateral damage ratio as content scanning for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try adding a custom form configuration file in the following guidance to your client so that there will be a column displaying the sender's email address in the message list:

**[Show sender’s e-mail address as a column in the Message List](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm)**

My test result in the following screenshot is for your reference:

[image]

If the sender's email address is a bit long, you could change the Reading Pane to bottom:

[image]

[image]

Besides, if you want to block the emails from the phishing sender, you could create an inbox or transport rule:

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, do you really expect users to know absolutely all phishing email addresses ahead of time to block them?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I was just making suggestions for the current scenario and the specific email address mentioned above.

Comment: You do, however, know all variations of the simplest form of this particular type of phishing trick and can express it in regular expressions. Just do not widely apply anti-lookalike rules to *second*-level domains, because a few of those (like com.au) are perfectly legitimate.